# No lookup on start for datasources in hibernate multi-tenant application

Tags: java, hibernate, datasource, multi-tenant

I am currently working on a **multi-tenant** application **using Spring and Hibernate with separate databases**. 
I would like **my application to work even if one of my datasources is inaccessible** (in case of problem), so that the other tenants can still access their data. That's why **I don't want my application to check the datasources at deployment time**. I tried to tell to not look up for datasources at start time :

```
applicationContext-datasources.xml :

<!-- data source 1 -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="ds1" jndi-name="jdbc/ds1" resource-ref="true" lookup-on-startup="false" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<!-- data source 2 -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="ds2" jndi-name="jdbc/ds2" resource-ref="true" lookup-on-startup="false" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

But I get this exception stack :

```
11:24:10,192 INFO  [STDOUT] 2014-11-28 11:24:10,189 - ERROR [main (ContextLoader.java:307) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jndi.JndiLookupFailureException: JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc not bound
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jndi.JndiLookupFailureException: JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc not bound
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:342)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.jndi.JndiLookupFailureException: JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc not bound
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectTargetSource.getTarget(JndiObjectTargetSource.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:182)
at $Proxy54.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.example.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.java:45)
at com.example.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.getAnyConnection(MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.java:31)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$MultiTenantConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:302)
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc not bound
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:529)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:537)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:543)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:267)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:625)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:587)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectTargetSource.getTarget(JndiObjectTargetSource.java:132)
...
```

If I **set lookup-on-startup with true in applicationContext-datasources.xml, then it works perfectly fine, but I know it won't work the day one of my datasources is inaccessible, even for the other tenant.**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve my goal, but the solution is not perfect.

When I declare my class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl, in the method getAnyConnection(), I give a connection from a default database, which is shared by all tenants :

```
public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider, Stoppable {

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return defaultDataSource.getConnection();
    }
    ...
}
```

And I let ths other methods determine the current tenant.

Then, in applicationContext-datasources.xml, I can declare all other datasources as I wished :

```
applicationContext-datasources.xml :

<!-- default data source -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="defaultDatasource" jndi-name="jdbc/defaultDatasource" resource-ref="true" lookup-on-startup="true" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<!-- data source 1 -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="ds1" jndi-name="jdbc/ds1" resource-ref="true" lookup-on-startup="false" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<!-- data source 2 -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="ds2" jndi-name="jdbc/ds2" resource-ref="true" lookup-on-startup="false" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

That way it works, but it requires a shared database.